# 500 Internal Server Error in simple Mean application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am doing a simple MEAN stack tutorial on Thinkster.io which involves creating a simple news app. When I try to post a new item to the server I get this  error, `POST http://localhost:3000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error)`. It is very vague and I have no idea how to debug it. In chrome I can only trace the error to this method.

```
//method in service
o.create = function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts', post).success(function(data) {
            o.posts.push(data);
    });
};
```

and

```
//usage
$scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === ""){
            return;
        }
        posts.create({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes : 0,
            comments: [
            {author: "Joe", body: "Class!!", upvotes: 0},
            {author: "Coco", body: "Woof Woof!!", upvotes: 0}
            ]
            })
        $scope.title = "";
        $scope.link = "";
};
```

But the problem is obviously in the backend. Even if you are unwilling to sift through the code please outline how I can debug this for myself. Here is a link to my repo.
[Link to Github](https://github.com/MultiplisJoseph/news-trends)

Chrome outputs

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/posts". angular.js:9818
POST http://localhost:3000/posts 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.js:9818
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/posts". angular.js:9818
```

CMD Outputs
[image]

Comment: There's no point in showing client-side code when the error is server-side.

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means problem in server side script

Comment: Yeah I realise this. Just felt it might show people the gist of what I am doing. @Phil

Comment: What does the console output look like from your server?

Comment: That looks like the logs from Chrome. What does the output look like on the actual server? It should be writing something in the console where you launched NodeJS

Comment: Yeah I re-edited it @chedabob

Comment: Why are you trying to add comments inside of the post create? You should add the comments after the post has already been saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments field on the Post model is expecting an array of comment ids. You are trying to create comments inside the create Post route. You should save the post as is and then add the comments after the fact. Or create comments first and pass an array of Ids to the comments field.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

CommentSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
}

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

I had to add/update the Comments.js file.

Answer (score 0):

*user.js*

If you are using this code for signup

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user")

router.post("/register", (req, res, next) =>{
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(hash =>{
        const user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash
        });
        user.save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "User created!",
                result: result
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(500).json({
                err:err 
            })
        })
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

*and angular file auth-service.ts *

So while signing up, this error occurs when you signup with the same mail
ok

```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthData } from "./auth-data.model";

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})

export class AuthService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {}

    createUser(email: string, password: string ){
        const authData: AuthData =  { email: email, password: password };
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/user/register", authData)
        .subscribe(Response =>{
            console.log(Response);
        })
    }
}
```